# I thought about some reasons for why the empty set is a subset of every set?is there some validity in them?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I have some reasons for why the empty set is a subset of every set,are they correct? i think they are.correct me if I'm wrong,or tell me more

I think the empty set being a subset of every set is like a notion of the idea that if everything in the universe is seen just as number of things, then the number representing collection of smallest number of things would be there in the number representing any collection of all things.

or another way of looking at it is if any collection of things is considered as a universe itself,then of course you could keep taking things away from it to make the collection smaller,and conclude this collection of things was inside what you originally had and conclude that nothing must be in it by the end of the process.

hence nothing is in everything.

One more idea is if it is not a subset of some set, then there must be something in it that is not there in the other set.

there is nothing in it.

hence the contradiction.

Comment: A set X is a subset of a set Y if every element of X is an element of Y. For any set Y whatever, every element of the empty set is vacuously an element of Y. In other words there are no elements of the empty set to falsify the proposition. Therefore the empty set is a subset of every set. There is no other reason. It follows from the definition of subset.

Comment: You can simply regard subset inclusion relation as part-whole mereology relation, then perhaps it's much easier to see empty set is a *subset* (as an empty part) of every set (as a whole), while it's not an *element* of every set...

Comment: @Double Knot 
by nothing in everything i do not mean the empty set is in everything,i mean the contents of empty set are in every collection of things.since almost everything in the universe can be seen as a collection,it could be that nothing is in everything.well atleast on macroscopic everyday life scales,or other ones too,idk i haven't studied till that level.think its true,or a sign why it works in math.well is it so wrong to share my views. :3 i don't tell you to accept them,i just ask do you think so too?if yes good,if not,well..its just a post not the end of the world.

Comment: It's a basic knowledge in modern standard ZF(C) set theory, without (weak) large cardinal axioms there's not a single model acting as a universe you happen to live inside ever pinned down except inner models such as Godel's constructible L as a transitive class, thus whether I agree with your proposition assuming I understand it fully or not, it perhaps won't be conclusive since per Godel's incompleteness consistency of ZFC is unsure so even proving it may be in vein. It seems you're confused about subset inclusion relation and membership relation which is the core of any type of set theory...

Comment: @Double alright,assuming the fact I do not know anything about which you speak,I know only elemntary high school set theory,so I guess you're right.but the argument does work for finite sets.

Comment: Emptyness is an extremely deep concept in philosophy and religions, it can be almost deduced from anything since it must be a *part* of everything as you correctly reasoned with your own understanding, but obviously not a token element instantiating an empty set since by definition an empty set doesn't have any element. As the ancient [Hear Sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/heartsutra/hs1.htm) hinted long ago: *Shariputra, all dharmas are empty of characteristics.  They are not produced. Not destroyed, not defiled, not  pure, and they neither increase nor diminish...*

Comment: @DoubleKnot I do not know you,but you seem to be a person who has seriously read a lot and i have respect for that surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the empty set being a subset of every set is like a notion of the idea that if everything in the universe is seen just as number of things, then the number representing collection of smallest number of things would be there in the number representing any collection of all things.

This shows that the empty set is *smaller* than the set of everything. It's a necessary condition, but not a *sufficient* one, for the subset relationship you're trying to show.

(∃x, ⊤) ⇒ (∀A, (∀x, x∈A) ⇒ |∅| ≤ |A|)

> or another way of looking at it is if any collection of things is considered as a universe itself,then of course you could keep taking things away from it to make the collection smaller,and conclude this collection of things was inside what you originally had and conclude that nothing must be in it by the end of the process.

This is a proof by induction – except backwards. This only really works to show that the empty set is a subset of all *finite* sets.

- ∀(A: Set), A=∅ ∨ ∃x, x∈A
- ∀(A: Set), ∀x, x∈A ⇒ (A∖{x}) ⊂ A
- ∴ ∀(A: Set), A=∅ ∨ ∃(B: Set), B⊂A
- Therefore, by induction and transitivity of ⊂, ∅ ⊂ A.

> One more idea is if it is not a subset of some set, then there must be something in it that is not there in the other set.
>
> there is nothing in it.
>
> hence the contradiction.

This one works for infinite sets as well as finite sets, but only if you take the [law of the excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle).

- ∀(A: Set), ∀(B: Set), B⊆A ⇔ ∀x, x∈B ⇒ x∈A
- ∴ ∀(A: Set), ∀(B: Set), B⊈A ⇔ ∃x, x∈B ∧ x∉A
- ∀x, x∉∅
- ∴ ∀(A: Set), ∅⊈A ⇒ ∃x, x∈∅ ∧ x∉A
- ∴ ∀(A: Set), ∅⊈A ⇒ ∃x, x∈∅
- But we know that ∀x, x∉∅ – therefore ∃x, x∈∅ is false!
- ∴ ∀(A: Set), ∅⊈A ⇒ ⊥
- ∴ (by the law of the excluded middle) ∀(A: Set), ∅⊆A

Comment: thank you,i just wished to know if there is some actual maths behind what i said.

Comment: @RishabhNarula Oh, okay. I'll try to formalise your arguments then.

Comment: i really dislike the third one, because the contradiction just sort of puts it in words and logic but doen't really visually show it like 2nd one could.why won't that work for infinite sets?

Comment: @RishabhNarula If you have an infinite set, you might not even be _able_ to select one! (See: [the axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice).) Also, my intuition says you can do something forever and still not exhaust an infinite set.

Comment: thanks for answering,maybe someday i'll sit down and try to understand the rigor version.

Comment: yeah,surely...don't know what to do when there are infinite things in the collection.but you can see it happen when things are finite is a good indicator for it to be a generally true statement.

Comment: But if infinite is doing,counting forever and you keep taking things out of infinite sets forever,won't you still reach same conclusion as the second one as i said.I mean could you exhaust infinite sets with infinite processes?

Comment: @RishabhNarula If you keep taking one integer, starting from the set of integers, you have the same-sized infinity of integers left over. Arguably you _could_ exhaust these, given infinite time, but the reals are _even bigger_ – so big you can't even count them – and I don't think you could exhaust those. But mathematics isn't really about our intuition; you can see what happens if you can, and see what happens if you can't; if one reaches a contradiction, there's your answer, and if neither does, you can choose whether it's possible.

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining

Comment: @RishabhNarula Oh, the rigorous version isn't particularly well-done, by the way; it's _technically correct_ (I think) but is really just a preciser version of what I thought you were saying. ∃ means "there exists", the comma means "such that" or "satisfying" or "where", ⇒ means "implies". Etc.

Comment: thanks for your time,really don't sweat it,i don't really understand our proof currently.I hope you knew what what you did? i wouldn't really sweat,its just some thoughts on this whole empty set being a subset of every set that i had.and wished to share to see what someonelse thinks...no big deal.its just a post.